# More than one function of a single instrumented endogenous variable -- is the model still underidentified?

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables, networks

**The typical instrumental variable setup** seeks a consistent estimate of $\beta$ from 
$$
y = \alpha + \beta x + \epsilon
$$
where $cor(x,\epsilon) \neq 0$, in the univariate case, without loss of generality, by instrumenting with some variable $z$ that is uncorrelated with $y$ conditional on $x$ (the "exclusion restriction").  $\hat\beta_{IV} = (Z'X)^{-1}Z'y$.  It can also be motivated as two-stage least squares, etc.  In the multivariate case, one generally needs at least as many instruments as endogenous variables.

**I've got a somewhat exotic case**, involving nodes in a network.  $y_i$ is an outcome for node $i$, and $x_i$ is an endogenous predictor of $y_i$.  I've got a single $z_i$ that is randomly assigned, and which predicts $x_i$ but not $y_i$, except through its effect on $x_i$.  It gets tricky when I consider that $y$ is also predicted by some $f(x_{-i})$ (i.e.: values of $x$ at other nodes).

The first stage model is something like 
$$
x_i = f(z_i) + \eta_i
$$
where $cor(z,\eta) = 0$

The second stage, represented as two-stage least squares, is something like
$$
y_i = \alpha + \beta_1\hat x_i + \beta_2 \hat u_i + \epsilon_i
$$

where $u_i = f(x_{-i},D_{-i})$ -- basically some function of the $x$'s of nearby $i$'s, and their distances $D$.  $\hat u$ is therefore $f(\hat x_{-i},D_{-i})$

So, I've got more endogenous variables than instruments, but my endogenous variables are all derived from a single endogenous variable, for which I have one instrument.

**My question**:  is my second stage underidentified?  Or just identified?  And why?

Comment: With nonlinear problems, you likely need independence rather than uncorrelatedness. My gut feeling is that you will be exactly identified, accounting also for nonlinearity. If your second stage is nonlinear as well through the network action, then God only knows how that works in terms of instrumenting and identification.